# Android OS using a lot of background data

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, background-data

My phone (Xperia P running Jellybean 4.1.2) is consuming a lot of background data (about 70 MB in just 15 minutes) Since, I have a restricted usage of 2 GB, it's causing a great problem. I've already disabled auto sync, background data and other related stuff. Don't know the reason. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you rooted?  If yes, then try Droidwall. Its an android firewall app which will give access to only those apps which you want thereby saving a lot of data. Hope this helps.